# gdb on mac 10.9 fails with "not in executable format: File format not recognized" for 32+64 arch

Tags: macos, g++, gdb

```
$ file app
app: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
app (for architecture i386):    Mach-O executable i386
app (for architecture x86_64):  Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64

$ gdb app
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
"app": not in executable format: File format not recognized


$ file test
test: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64

$ gdb test
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /Users/dmulder/test...Reading symbols from /Users/dmulder/test.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/test...done.
done.
```

Why would the 64bit binary succeed, but the 64+32 binary fail?

Comment: Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: I built gdb from source, by the way (yesterday).

Comment: is your "`app`" in an application package?  i.e. are you trying to do "`gdb app`" when you should be doing "`gdb app.app/Contents/MacOS/app`"? (i.e. the true binary is buried in the application package)

Comment: @David Good point, I installed gdb via Xcode, do you have xcode? can you send me the permalink to the file so I can test it here? put it on dropbox or something... (i delete the answer until come up w/ something concrete)

Comment: You can't install gdb via xcode on Mac 10.9. Of course I have xcode installed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Unfortunately, the non-Apple version of GNU gdb is currently unable to debug universal (or 'fat') binaries (ones that contain both 32-bit and 64-bit executables).

One option is to use `lipo` to extract a single architecture and run gdb on that:

```
lipo -thin x86_64 -output app-x86_64 ./app
```

or

```
lipo -thin i386 -output app-i386 ./app
```

If you'd prefer to debug the combined executable, you could try using [LLDB](http://lldb.llvm.org/), or an [Apple version of gdb](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/gdb/).

Comment: I ended up downloading and compiling Apple's version of gdb here http://www.opensource.apple.com/release/developer-tools-46/ and that worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

As OP [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20553784/gdb-on-mac-10-9-fails-with-not-in-executable-format-file-format-not-recognized#comment31528526_20975057), using Apple's gdb will fix the problem.

Here are instructions to build Apple gdb 6.3.50.20050815-cvs from source on OS 10.9:

**NOTE:** You will need to install Xcode and set up a build environment. If you have [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) installed, run `brew doctor` to see if "Your system is ready to brew."

1. Download the gdb-1822 source tarball from: http://opensource.apple.com/tarballs/gdb/gdb-1822.tar.gz
2. Extract this into a temporary directory. Open a terminal and `cd` into `gdb-1822/src`.
3. Run the `configure` script:

   ```
   ./configure --prefix="$HOME/.local/stow/gdb-1822" --disable-debug --disable-dependency-tracking --with-system-readline
   ```

   (The last three configure arguments are from the homebrew-dupes formula: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes/blob/master/gdb.rb )
4. Run make:

   ```
   make
   make install
   ```
5. Follow the instructions at https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/BuildingOnDarwin#Creating_a_certificate to create a gdb-cert code signing certificate.
6. `cd` into `$HOME/.local/stow/gdb-1822/bin` and sign the `gdb` executable:

   ```
   codesign -s gdb-cert gdb
   ```
7. `cd` into `$HOME/.local/stow` and [stow](https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/) the `gdb-1822` folder:

   ```
   stow gdb-1822
   ```
8. Add `$HOME/.local/bin` to your `PATH` and either restart the terminal or [clear Bash's cache](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5609/3535) to the location of `gdb`:

   ```
   hash -d gdb
   ```

Comment: Why would `brew install gdb` produce this exact same problem ... NOW?