# XCode 5 remote debugging of OS X apps

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode5, osx-mavericks

I'm developing an app on OS X 10.9 created with XCode 5.0.2 and got a bug report which I cannot reproduce on this dev machine. However, I have a 10.7 Virtual Machine that exhibits the crash, so I would like to debug there without installing XCode in this VM.

I searched for informations on remote debugging, but I got no useful answer. I'm even afraid it is not supported at all. But I have to ask anyway to be sure.

Alternatively, what other options exist to debug such a problem other than doing a full XCode installation etc.?

Comment: I don't know of any remote debugging facilities. As for alternatives, there are many resources: https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=debugging+without+a+debugger&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8

Comment: Yes, right, this is how I solved my problem at hand (using logging). But shouldn't there be such a thing like a remote debugger (and be it only a command line tool for lldb or gdb)?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is probably to just install XCode in the virtual machine, and debug it there. Alternatively, it is possible to just install gdb or lldb without installing all of XCode:

**GDB**
[GDB missing in OS X Mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19554439/gdb-missing-in-os-x-mavericks)

**LLDB**
http://lldb.llvm.org/build.html