# How can I find out if I have Xcode commandline tools installed?

Tags: xcode, macos, installation, command-line

I need to use gdb.

```
ps-MacBook-Air:AcoustoExport pi$ gdb
-bash: gdb: command not found

ps-MacBook-Air:AcoustoExport pi$ sudo find / -iname "*gdb*"
Password:
/usr/local/share/gdb
/usr/local/Cellar/isl/0.12.1/share/gdb
:
```

and:

```
ps-MacBook-Air:AcoustoExport pi$ ls -la /usr/local/share/gdb
lrwxr-xr-x   1 pi    admin   30 14 Jan 22:01 gdb -> ../Cellar/isl/0.12.1/share/gdb
```

Not quite sure what to make this, clearly it is something installed by homebrew. I don't know why it's there, I don't know whether I could use it instead. It isn't in the search path.

So I figure I need Xcode commandline tools.

[Xcode is not currently available from the Software Update server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19907576/xcode-is-not-currently-available-from-the-software-update-server)

^ my current problem exactly.  Comment on that question says "you can get this error if you have them already"

But how do I check whether I have them already?

Answer (score 324, accepted):

```
/usr/bin/xcodebuild -version
```

will give you the xcode version, run it via Terminal command

Comment: To get only the version use the following command:

/usr/bin/xcodebuild -version | sed -En 's/Xcode[[:space:]]+([0-9\.]*)/\1/p'

Comment: I am getting error with the mentioned command. "-bash: /usr/build/xcodebuild: No such file or directory." I have confirmed that I have xcode by running command gcc --version, which gives the gcc details. I am on Mac OS X 10.13.6.

Comment: @GAURAV SRIVASTAVA: it's `/usr/bin`, not `/usr/build`. In fact `xcodebuild` should be enough since `/usr/bin` is usually in your `PATH`.

Comment: I get this `xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance`. i think

Comment: @GulamHussain, see below answer by @Alex https://stackoverflow.com/a/42144725/311288 for cases where Xcode not installed and only  `CommandLineTools` is available

Comment: On Monterey zsh this outputs: `MacBook-Pro ~ % /usr/bin/xcodebuild -version
xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance` However, I'm pretty sure I have XCode installed for git... I don't remember now. I'm just trying to get through a warning from Symfony CLI.

Answer (score 94):

This command allows you to retrieve Xcode version when having only the  `CommandLineTools` version installed:

```
pkgutil --pkg-info=com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables | grep version
```

As per [this answer to "Determine xcode command line tools version" on Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/181994/222496)

Notes:

- Confirmed working on maxOS Sierra and Big Sur.
- When only CommandLineTools is install without Xcode, using xcodebuild returns the following error:

```
# /usr/bin/xcodebuild -version
xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance
```

Comment: Thank you! This actually works when only *CommandLineTools* is installed and not actual *Xcode* and solves the error when running`/usr/bin/xcodebuild -version` :

`xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance`

Comment: On Monterey (12.5), I get the following: `No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables' found at '/'.` Ideas? (I only have the cmd-line tools installed, not Xcode.)

Comment: Thanks. Worked fine on Monterey (12.6.1).

Comment: I get the same problem as @wescpy using Monterey 12.6.2.

Answer (score 57):

First of all, be sure that you have downloaded it or not. Open up your terminal application, and enter `$ gcc` if  you have not installed it you will get an alert. You can verify that you have installed it by

```
$ xcode-select -p
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

And to be sure then enter `$ gcc --version`

You can read more about the process here: [Xcode command line tools for Mavericks](http://railsapps.github.io/xcode-command-line-tools.html)

Comment: @Pi What do you get when you enter $gcc --version?
Do you get something like this:
--prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)

Comment: No, I get --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr. The remainder is the same as your printout.

Answer (score 49):

> if you want to know the install version of Xcode as well as Swift
>   language current version:

Use below simple command by using Terminal:

***1. To get install Xcode Version***

```
 xcodebuild -version
```

***2. To get install Swift language Version***

```
swift --version
```

Answer (score 16):

Thanks to the folks on Freenode's #macdev, here is some information:

In the old days before Xcode was on the app-store, it included commandline tools.

Now you get it from the store, and with this new mechanism it can't install extra things outside of the Xcode.app, so you have to manually do it yourself, by:

```
xcode-select --install
```

On Xcode 4.x you can check to see if they are installed from within the Xcode 
UI:

[image]

On Xcode 5.x it is now here:

[image]

My problem of finding gcc/gdb is that they have been superseded by clang/lldb: [GDB missing in OS X v10.9 (Mavericks)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19554439/gdb-missing-in-os-x-mavericks)

Also note that Xcode contains compiler and debugger, so one of the things installing commandline tools will do is symlink or modify $PATH.  It also downloads certain things like git.

Comment: Answer still useful and relevant for xcode 15

Answer (score 6):

The answers suggesting to use `xcodebuild -version` are correct but sadly the output is formatted like so:

```
Xcode 14.3
Build version 14E222b
```

If you need the version of Xcode without the "Xcode " prefix, you can run the following:

```
xcodebuild -version | awk '/Xcode/ {print $2}' | tr -d '\n'
```

Answer (score 5):

If for some reason xcode is not installed under

`/usr/bin/xcodebuild`

execute the following command

`which xcodebuild`

and if it is installed, you'll be prompted with it's location.

Answer (score 5):

#### TL;DR

One can have multiple installations of Xcode and multiple installations of Command Line Tools. This is where the system thinks your CLT are

```
xcode-select --print-path
```

Options to select Command Line Tools is in Xcode > Preferences > Locations, including the path for each. I found that `brew` complains about Xcode or Command Line Tools, and so following details how to install specific version of either.

### brew doctor issues after upgrade MacOS

I have always used App store to install and update Xcode on my (2014) Macbook Pro but today after all updates `brew doctor` was still complaining about Xcode

> Warning: Your Xcode (12.4) is outdated.
> Please update to Xcode 13.2.1 (or delete it).

and complaining about Command Line Tools

> Warning: A newer Command Line Tools release is available.

#### Get the specific version of Xcode

- Download a specific version of Xcode as a `xip` from [Developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=Xcode)  (I downloaded Xcode_13.2.1.xip)
- Move Xcode_13.2.1.xip to /Applications

  cd Applications
  xip --expand /Applications/Xcode_13.2.1.xip

It takes a while to download, then a while longer to validate the application.
Open /Applications/Xcode.app

#### Check the CLT in XCode

[Xcode> Preferences> Locations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfDvp.png) shows available CLT and the location (path) of each.
Select the appropriate Command Line Tools
Copy the path.
Go to Terminal and use the path in xcode-select
`sudo xcode-select -s /Users/<username>/Applications/Xcode.app`
Close Terminal and reopen.
The following was not specific enough:
`pkgutil --pkg-info=com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables | grep version`
But this is good to identify the version

```
$ /usr/bin/xcodebuild -version
```

> Xcode 13.2.1
> Build version 13C100

IF still showing an older version of CLT
Try

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/
```

THEN try

#### Update to a specific version of CLT

First, remove the existing CLT with

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

Check which CLT updates available

```
softwareupdate --list
```

> Software Update Tool
> Finding available software
> Software Update found the following new or updated software:
>
> - Label: Command Line Tools for Xcode-12.4
>   Title: Command Line Tools for Xcode, Version: 12.4, Size: 440392K,>  Recommended: YES,
> - Label: Command Line Tools for Xcode-13.2
>   Title: Command Line Tools for Xcode, Version: 13.2, Size: 577329K,>  Recommended: YES,
> - Label: Command Line Tools for Xcode-12.5
>   Title: Command Line Tools for Xcode, Version: 12.5, Size: 470966K,>  Recommended: YES,
> - Label: Command Line Tools for Xcode-12.5
>   Title: Command Line Tools for Xcode, Version: 12.5, Size: 470820K,>  Recommended: YES,

```
softwareupdate --install "Command Line Tools for Xcode-13.2"
```

Closed Terminal and reopen

```
/usr/bin/xcodebuild -version
```

> Xcode 13.2.1
> Build version 13C100

Output from:

```
$ xcode-select -p
```

`/Users/<username>/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

And `brew doctor` shows

> Your system is ready to brew.

Answer (score 4):

I had XCode Commandline Tools installed for sure, but not XCode itself.

None of the available answers to get the version worked. `pkgutil` didn't give me the package of the XCode Commandline Tools, with none of the suggested package names.

Not having XCode installed (and having no need for it), I could not look in settings dialogs of that either.

`xcode-select --version` only gave me the version of `xcode-select` itself, with no clue as to the commandline tools version.

`softwareupdate --list` told me everything was up to date.

However I knew that my version must be out of date as the installer for one of homebrew packages told me so!

How I finally found out what version of the XCode Commandline Tools is installed I stumbled upon the command:

```
softwareupdate --history
```

Which listed 12.3 as the last version it updated...

```
Display Name                                       Version    Date                  
------------                                       -------    ----                  
Safari                                             14.0       04/11/2020, 12:26:12  
Command Line Tools for Xcode                       12.1       04/11/2020, 22:38:33  
Safari                                             14.0.2     15/12/2020, 16:38:27  
Safari                                             14.0.1     15/12/2020, 16:38:27  
Command Line Tools for Xcode                       12.3       15/12/2020, 16:38:27  
macOS Big Sur                                      11.2.1     14/02/2021, 20:57:56  
macOS Big Sur 11.2.2                               11.2.2     08/03/2021, 09:02:20
```

So when you know for sure the commandline tools are installed (because, for instance, `xcode-select --install` tells you so) but none of the other methods works, check `softwareupdate --history`!

Answer (score 2):

You can open the Xcode app and go to preferences, the last line shows you if you have tools installed, which tools and lets you change them from the drop-down:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed Xcode but haven't set the Xcode version. then you will be getting this error. To resolve
Xcode-> preferences -> Locations -> command line Tools -> Select the Xcode version

Answer (score 0):

For macOS catalina try this : open Xcode. if not existing. download from App store (about 11GB) then open Xcode>open developer tool>more developer tool and used my apple id to download a compatible command line tool. Then, after downloading, I opened Xcode>Preferences>Locations>Command Line Tool and selected the newly downloaded command line tool from downloads.